# Rails “helpers” are very specifically view helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been reading about Good Manners of Rails, and there are many articles like this one:

http://codefol.io/posts/Where-Do-I-Put-My-Code/

and seems like helpers should only be used for views. I don't understand well why, but if that would be the case and this is my **sessions_helper.rb** file:

```
module SessionsHelper
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def log_off
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user&.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end

  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_digest
  end

  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
end
```

and this is my model **user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :post
  attr_accessor :remember_token, :activation_token
  before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
  before_create :create_activation_digest
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i.freeze
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }

  # Returns the hash digest of the given string.
  def self.digest(string)
    Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(string.to_s)
  end

  # Returns a random token.
  def self.new_token
    SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end

  # Remembers a user in the database for use in persistent sessions.
  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end

  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(remember_token)
    return false if remember_digest.nil?

    BCrypt::Password.new(remember_digest).is_password?(remember_token)
  end

  # Forgets a user.
  def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
  end

  # Creates and assigns the activation token and digest.
  def create_activation_digest
    self.activation_token = User.new_token
    self.activation_digest = User.digest(activation_token)
  end
end
```

what should I do to refactor it in a good way to be correct?

sorry If I am requesting too much help, but it is just that I am learning Rails and I don't understand this part very well.

Comment: Rails helpers are for views, basically formatting text for the html page. What you have put in module SessionsHelper does not look like helpers at all. It's more a controller actions. (or a module methods, yet not a helper module)

Comment: @Maxence nonsense. There are tons of reasons why you would want to use `logged_in?`, `current_user` etc in the view as well.

Comment: @max You are using edge cases as an argument to invalidate my comment.

Comment: @Maxence i'm using real life to prove its not black and white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To satisfy my supervisor (or code reviewer), I had to copy/paste all session helper code on every single controller file, since copying it in application_controller was not enough.

Comment: Omg. He is the uncrowned king of job security

Comment: Does he do version control by copying the file and adding a date to the file name as well?

Comment: ehmmmm no, I have never seen that before :v only in migration files that are created by default with the date.

Answer (score 1):

That article is really just states the authors opinion. `AbstractController::Helpers` actually has [`helper`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper) method thats used to specifically include helpers into the controller so its hardly an officially endorsed opinion.

It can be debated endlessly exactly where exactly this peice of code belongs but since you're going to be using it in both the view and controller I would say just put it in `app/helpers` and be done with it. It makes a lot more sense than placing it somewhere else and then manually including it in the view context.

However this code should probally be split into two modules as only part of it makes sense to use from the view.

```
module SessionsHelper
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.signed[:user_id])
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user&.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in user
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
# app/controllers/concerns/authenticable.rb
module Authenticable
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def log_off
    forget(current_user)
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

  def remember(user)
    user.remember
    cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_digest
  end

  def forget(user)
    user.forget
    cookies.delete(:user_id)
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
end
```

Comment: The main problem with helpers is that they just end up as junk drawer as the whole term is extremely vague. I doubt this stupid dogma really helps with that.

Comment: And there are more important best practices you really should be thinking about instead like not reinventing the authentication wheel.